# Flow.Run selected text from Dropdown

Tags: powerapps

Been trying to figure out why this wont work for the past few hours. Googled as much as I could with no luck. I'm trying to select the text from a dropdown to then hit the "button" and it import to SQL. I can get it to work if I just you text fields, but for some reason the dropdown will just not work no matter what I do....

```
SQLInsert.Run(WorkOrder.SelectedText, Status.Value, Date.text);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending how your dropdown is configured, addressing the control returns a record. You want to get the value of the selected record in the dropdown. So, change (assuming that your dropdown is called "Status")

```
Status.Value
```

to

```
Status.Selected.Value
```

Don't just copy and paste that. Type it in and watch the intellisense, because depending on how the dropdown is set up, the "Value" may actually be something different, but it will show in the intellisense after you type `Status.Selected.`

Edit: If the dropdown is not called Status, but something else, like `Workorder`, just use `Workorder` instead of `Status` (am I really writing this?)

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: The Status is just for the "On" and "Off" switch. The Workorder is the drop down. Using Selected.Value on the dropdown or Selected.Text still results in the same error.

Comment: Change `Workorder.SelectedText` to `Workorder.Selected.Value` (or `.whateverIntellisenseSays`) like @teylyn suggested.

Comment: Well, from your screenshot I could not see what the dropdown control's name is, so I guessed and used Status. Can you make the leap and use `Workorder` instead of `Status` to apply the fix??